# How to set Log scale as radius in force directed graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to set log scale in force directed graph using d3.js?

The Minimum and maximum value of domain is **0.36** and **15926.29**

Here is my code below.

```
var hitsscale = d3.scale.log().base(10)
    .domain([d3.min(nodes.filter(function(d){return d.group==1;}), function(d) { return d.value; }),
             d3.max(nodes.filter(function(d){return d.group==1;}), function(d) { return d.value; })]);

d3.selectAll(".circle")
    .append("circle")
    .style("fill",function(d){return color(d.group);})
    .attr("r",function(d){return hitsscale(d.value); })
    .attr('class',function(d){ 
    //return d.type + d.node_name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/gi, ""); 
    return d.type + d.node_name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/gi, "") +" "+"A"+d.value.toString().replace('.',""); 
    })
;
```

I am setting logarithmic scale as radius in force directed graph. The main issue is that circle is not visible.

Comment: circle is not visible coz you are not setting the cx and cy

Comment: @Cyril This is not necessarily true. `cx` and `cy` will default to zero, thus centering the circle at the origin of the coordinate system. When appending the circle to a group, which has a transformation, the circle might or might not be rendered in the visible viewport.

Comment: I agree with you @altocumulus but in the snippet above do you see any transform..there will be some small circle huddled in the corner :)

Comment: @Cyril I did my homework ;-) Some two months ago I posted an [answer](/q/33229120) to one of OP's questions which seems to be dealing with the same code. It's just guessing, but it rang a bell. Looking at that question's SVG you're going to see the `g`s having class `circle` with a transformation applied to each one of them.

Comment: Without some more information this comes down to guessing what the real issue might be. Please try to set up a live demo demonstrating your problem.